# Regex to select url except when = is directly infront of it

Tags: php, regex

I'm trying to use a regex to find and replace all URLs in a forum system. This works but it also selects anything that is within bbcode. This shouldn't be happening.

My code is as follows:

```
<?php
function make_links_clickable($text){
    return preg_replace('!(([^=](f|ht)tp(s)?://)[-a-zA-Zа-яА-Я()0-9@:%_+.~#?&;//=]+)!i', '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $text);
}
//$text = "https://www.mcgamerzone.com<br>http://www.mcgamerzone.com/help/support<br>Just text<br>http://www.google.com/<br><b>More text</b>";
$text = "@Theareak We know this and [b][url=https://www.mcgamerzone.com/news/67/False-positive-proxy-bans-and-bot-attacks]here[/url] [/b]is an explanation, we are trying to fix this asap! https://www.mcgamerzone.com/news/67/False-positive-proxy-bans-and-bot-attacks aaa";
echo "<b>Unparsed text:</b><br>";
echo $text;
echo "<br><br>";
echo "<b>Parsed text:</b><br>";
echo make_links_clickable($text);
?>
```

All urls that occur in bb-code are following up on a = character, meaning that I don't want anything that starts with = to be selected.

I basically have that working but this results in selecting 1 extra character in in front of the string that should be selected.

I'm not very familiar with regex. The final output of my code is this:

[image: My HTML]

```
<b>Unparsed text:</b><br>
@Theareak We know this and&nbsp;&#65279;[b][url=https://www.mcgamerzone.com/news/67/False-positive-proxy-bans-and-bot-attacks]here[/url]&nbsp;[/b]is an explanation, we are trying to fix this asap! https://www.mcgamerzone.com/news/67/False-positive-proxy-bans-and-bot-attacks aaa<br>
<br>
<b>Parsed text:</b><br>
@Theareak We know this and&nbsp;&#65279;[b][url=https://www.mcgamerzone.com/news/67/False-positive-proxy-bans-and-bot-attacks]here[/url]&nbsp;[/b]is an explanation, we are trying to fix this asap!<a href=" https://www.mcgamerzone.com/news/67/False-positive-proxy-bans-and-bot-attacks"> https://www.mcgamerzone.com/news/67/False-positive-proxy-bans-and-bot-attacks</a> aaa
```

Comment: Rather than a negated class, you should use a negative lookbehind `(?<!=)`

Comment: Could do something like https://regex101.com/r/yV2oD6/1.

Comment: @Aaron can you post an example for me?

Comment: You can try `(((f|ht)tps?://)[-a-zA-Zа-яёЁА-Я()0-9@:%_+.\~#?&;//=]+)(?![^\]]*])`

Comment: I'm not very familiar with PHP regex which is why I didn't post an answer, but I'll try

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can match and skip `[url=...]` like this:

```
\[url=[^\]]*](*SKIP)(?!)|(((f|ht)tps?://)[-a-zA-Zа-яёЁА-Я()0-9@:%_+.\~#?&;/=]+)
```

See [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uS3lG2/3)

That way, you will only match the URLs outside the `[url=...]` tag.

[IDEONE demo](http://ideone.com/PNUxCQ):

```
function make_links_clickable($text){
    return preg_replace('~\[url=[^\]]*](*SKIP)(?!)|(((f|ht)tps?://)[-a-zA-Zа-яёЁА-Я()0-9@:%_+.\~#?&;/=]+)~iu', '<a href="$1">$1</a>', $text);
}
$text = "@Theareak We know this and [b][url=https://www.mcgamerzone.com/news/67/False-positive-proxy-bans-and-bot-attacks]here[/url] [/b]is an explanation, we are trying to fix this asap! https://www.mcgamerzone.com/news/67/False-positive-proxy-bans-and-bot-attacks aaa";
echo "<b>Parsed text:</b><br>";
echo make_links_clickable($text);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use a negative lookbehind `(?<!=)` instead of your negated class. It asserts that what is going to be matched isn't preceded by something.

[Example](https://eval.in/514187)

Comment: PHP example, https://eval.in/514187, also don't forget to group the whole URL. Also `s` doesn't need to be grouped the `?` can just go right on it.

Comment: Thanks for the PHP example, I'll change mine. Do you care to explain why you should group the whole url? Isn't it possible to retrieve the whole match?

Comment: This approach just helps to avoid matching URLs after a `=`, but not outside `[url=...]` tag.

Comment: Oh yea, could use the `0` grouping. I prefer defining my grouped things. This would work with the `$0` though and no additional grouping.